# Typescript: Requiring matched type

Tags: typescript

```
interface MsgEvent {
    readonly    data:   any; // 1 to 1 copy from MessageEvent<any>
}

interface MsgPort {
    postMessage:    (message: any) => void; // 1 to 1 copy from MessagePort
    onmessage:      ((ev: MsgEvent) => any) | null; // 1 to 1 copy from MessagePort
}

class Sup<X extends MsgPort> {

}

class Child extends Sup<MessagePort> {

}
```

With this code we just assign `MessagePort` type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort) to X, but X has to extends our custom `MsgPort`. As You can see, requirement is fulfilled but Typescript thinks it's not:

```
Type 'MessagePort' does not satisfy the constraint 'MsgPort'.
  Types of property 'onmessage' are incompatible.
    Type '((this: MessagePort, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any) | null' is not assignable to type '((ev: MsgEvent) => any) | null'.
      Type '(this: MessagePort, ev: MessageEvent<any>) => any' is not assignable to type '(ev: MsgEvent) => any'.
        Types of parameters 'ev' and 'ev' are incompatible.
          Type 'MsgEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'MessageEvent<any>': lastEventId, origin, ports, source, and 23 more.ts(2344)
```

The `this: MessagePort,`  part doesn't matter, I've checked it already.

When we try skip `MsgPort`, and just use `MsgEvent` along with `MessageEvent<any>` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent/MessageEvent) then everything works:

```
class Sup<X extends MsgEvent> {

}

class Child extends Sup<MessageEvent<any>> {

}
```

It seems to be a bug in Typescript, but maybe I don't see it's my mistake? It surely should works, because Typescript officialy allowes assigning Bigger type to Smaller type if Bigger extends Smaller.

Comment: It's your mistake; functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types (so `(x: T)=>void extends (x: U)=>void` if `U` extends `T`, not vice versa).  A true `MessagePort` expects that its `onmessage` will be passed a true `MessageEvent<any>`, and can thus dereference properties in it.  But your `MsgPort`'s `onmessage` method will accept things without those properties, allowing for a runtime error if you had your way, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N55K9N).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: `onmessage` is listener callback, so I have control what is called inside it, my code only utilizes the `data` param of `MsgEvent`/`MessageEvent<any>` so everything should be fine

Comment: Right now your `Sup` and `Child` examples don't even depend structurally on their type arguments so it's hard to show you a particular example of what's going wrong here.  But the point is that `Child extends Sup<MessagePort>`, not `Sup<MsgPort>`.  So somewhere there's the possibility that an actual `MessagePort` is treated like a `MsgPort` and you could get a runtime error, but your example isn't complete.  Could you [edit] your example to actually use its type parameter?

Comment: Like, if `Sup<X>` has a property of type `X`, then [this is the problem](https://tsplay.dev/wE79Vm).  But if not, how does `Sup<X>` depend on `X`?

Comment: `onmessage` is always called by Browser/NodeJS engine, not by user's code, I guess typescript just lacks keyword sth like `writeonly and readonly, but not callable` then it could be resolved safely. Everything I do with `onmessage` property is just assign callback, that's all, I never call it by myself.

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed here without a [mre] that shows how `Sup<X>` depends on `X` and how `Child` is being constructed.  If the only thing that calls `onmessage` is going to pass in a full `MessageEvent<any>` then why not just use that type as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8k5W)?  If I see the code get [edit]ed with an example I'll continue to engage; otherwise, good luck!